# Hibernate ManyToMany relationship with a abstract class

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am trying to model simple book-renting classes.

I've defined the following class hierarchy:

```
@Entity 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) 
public abstract class StockItem { }


@Entity
public class Book extends StockItem {}


@Entity
public class RentalBook extends Book {}
```

Now theres one problem I have encountered. I'd like to add a class that represents photo of StockItems, in a N:N relationship:

```
@Entity
public class ItemPhoto {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "items_photos",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "photo_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    )
    private List<StockItem> items;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class StockItem {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "items_photos",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "photo_id")
    )
    private List<ItemPhoto> photos;
}
```

The code compiled, tables had been created, but Hibernate didn't generate FK for StockItem PK. The table items_photos contains only FK of Photo's PK.

I know that it's because of defining `StockItem` abstract.

Is there any way I can achieve that kind of mapping on a abstract class?

Comment: You have a table per class - no FK is possible.

Comment: Is it something i should be concerned about? Will the mapping work as intented (only with the FK missing), or it's a completely invalid approach?

Comment: It will work but you can't have a FK for this.